# Uploading files using design pattern with python

Tags: python, django, design-patterns

I used to upload csv, excel, json or geojson files in my a postegreSQL using Python/Django.
I noticed that the scripts is redundant and sometimes difficult to maintain when we need to update key or columns. Is there a way to use design pattern? I have never used it before.
Any suggestion or links could be hep!

Comment: i don't understand your question properly. correct me when I am wrong. So you are adding data in DB using Django( orm right ?). When you get the data from this files so when the id is exist you need to update the value and if id doesn't exist then you want to create??

Comment: Yes, I am uploading data in DB using Django. The problem is I have so many table with differents variables. So the script for uploading let's say CSV file is the same except, I have to deals with columns since they are not the same from a file to another